# Show Currency Symbol after values

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, string-formatting, currency

I am using CultureInfo methods to successfully format all different currencies into their correct format.

But on some exceptions, such as EUR and SEK currencies I need to be able to add them after the value. At the moment my CultureInfo is formatting them in the following way: "SEK 1.00,00" when it needs to be "1.00,00 SEK".

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All you need is to change the [`NumberFormatInfo.CurrencyPositivePattern`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencypositivepattern.aspx) and [`NumberFormatInfo.CurrencyNegativePattern`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencynegativepattern.aspx) properties for the culture.

Just clone the original culture:

```
CultureInfo swedish = new CultureInfo("sv-SE");
swedish = (CultureInfo)swedish.Clone();
swedish.NumberFormat.CurrencyPositivePattern = 3;
swedish.NumberFormat.CurrencyNegativePattern = 3;
```

and then

```
var value = 123.99M;
var result = value.ToString("C", swedish);
```

should give you desired result. This should get you:

> 123,99 kr

Comment: Yes that works! Thanks Alex. Just so that I understand what you done. All I needed was to add CurrencyPositivePattern and CurrencyNegativePattern methods to move the currency symbol to the end?

Comment: @R100: yep, but these are the properties(not methods) of `NumberFormatInfo` class.

Answer (score 3):

Be careful about the CurrencyNegativePattern

This code

```
CultureInfo swedish = new CultureInfo("sv-SE");
swedish = (CultureInfo)swedish.Clone();
swedish.NumberFormat.CurrencyPositivePattern = 3;
swedish.NumberFormat.CurrencyNegativePattern = 3;
```

Will give you

> 134,99 kr.
>
> kr.134,99kr.-

Changing CurrencyNegativePattern to 8

```
swedish.NumberFormat.CurrencyNegativePattern = 8;
```

Will give you

> 134,99 kr.
>
> -134,99 kr.

More info https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencynegativepattern(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{0:C}", moneyValue.DataAmount)
```

Comment: If this solves the problem, an explanation would make this a better answer