# How to force currency symbol to right side of number?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a DisplayFormat attribute on my decimal property, to show it as a currency:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C0}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public decimal Price { get; set; }
```

This is how I print it in the view:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Price)
```

If the value of Price is 3000, it displays as:

```
kr. 3.000
```

But I want it to show with the currency to the right of the amount, as:

```
3.000 kr.
```

How can I do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5272868/795683

Comment: Try a custom format like those shown in the duplicate's answer, eg `{0:#,### $}`. The answer shows how to use different formats for negative values and 0 as well

Answer (score 0):

The currency format in use is defined by the relevant `CultureInfo` instance.

Some methods have overloads which take an `IFormatProvider` (implemented by `CultureInfo`), otherwise the default `CultureInfo` from `Thread.CurrentCulture`. The latter case applies when using the Razor helpers.

Specifically the [`CultureInfo.NumberFormat.CurrencyPositivePattern`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencypositivepattern?view=netframework-4.7) and [`.CurrencyNegativePattern`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencynegativepattern?view=netframework-4.7) determine the placement of the currency symbol.

You can, using [`CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureandregioninfobuilder?view=netframework-4.7), create a custom culture with different settings.

However you might be better adding your own currency specific helper, that uses a custom `NumberFormatInfo`, possibly via a Razor display template and using [`UIHintAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.uihintattribute?view=netframework-4.7.1) to specify properties that should use that display template.

Answer (score 0):

### Update

This property C (standard format define positive currency values) has one of the values in the following table. The symbol "$" is the CurrencySymbol and n is a number.

- 0 results in $n
- 1 results in n$
- 2 results in $ n
- 3 results in n $

---

so that clone the original culture:

```
CultureInfo swedish = new CultureInfo("sv-SE");
swedish = (CultureInfo)swedish.Clone();
swedish.NumberFormat.CurrencyPositivePattern = 3;
swedish.NumberFormat.CurrencyNegativePattern = 3;
```

---

Review that [Show Currency Symbol after values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272760/show-currency-symbol-after-values/5272868#5272868)
and that [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencypositivepattern(v=vs.110).aspx) also

Comment: The number in the format string is the [number of decimal digits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#the-currency-c-format-specifier), not the currency placement.

Comment: You are correct @PanagiotisKanavos, I will update the answer now,thanks for your correction.